# Why are uncompressed binary objects in R acting compressed and slow to read?

Tags: r, performance, compression

I need to frequently read large objects, so I want the highest possible read rate. I save the objects with `save(..., compress = F)`. Two things have me wondering if R is really saving the objects as binary, uncompressed files:

1. The bottleneck for both read and write rates is the CPU, running at 100%, not my disk's maximum rates.
2. The objects appear to be smaller on disk than in memory (e.g. 944,696,761 B on disk, 973,970,512 B in R according to object.size()).

Uncompressed files read at 75-85 MB/s, compared to ~30 MB/s for reading compressed files; this rate is the same from my external hard drive and my SSD, well under the capacity for each.

So my question is: does this make sense? Shouldn't the read/write run at the disk's limit? Is there another option that will?

---

Details:

The compress = F argument does, as expected, both increase the file size on disk (about threefold), and definitely does improve both write and read speed (20-fold and 2.5-fold, respectively); yet the CPU remains the bottleneck, grinding away at 100% for the duration of the read or write. This feels to me like a light compression.

For the files saved with compress = F, Nautilus's properties window reports the files' type to be "Binary (application/octet-stream)".

The read takes over than twice as long as the write (e.g. 50.5s vs. 22s for 4.3 GB). I don't know why that would be.

I have a new SSD (sequential non-cached read speed (`hdparm -t`) of at least 265 MB/s).